# How can I check for the existence of an XML node in Flex/AS3?

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript-3, namespaces

Why does the trace in the loop below return `false` for every iteration, even though there ARE nodes named with 6 of the 8 possible values??? This only happens when I have a namespace. Is there some other way to check for the node values???

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            private namespace ltrs = "letters";

            use namespace ltrs;

            private var myArray:Array = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"];

            private function checkXML():void
            {
                for each (var p:String in myArray)
                {
                    trace(myXML.hasOwnProperty(p).toString()); // returns false;
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:XML id="myXML">
        <root xmlns="letters">
            <a>true</a>
            <b>true</b>
            <c>true</c>
            <e>true</e>
            <f>true</f>
            <g>true</g>
        </root>
    </mx:XML>

    <mx:Button click="checkXML();" />
</mx:Application>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method hasOwnProperty just doesn't work with XML nodes. I believe this is to the E4X specification. However, you can always ask for a node with E4X even if it's not there and just see what the length of the XMLList is that you get back. Like so:

```
trace(myXML[p].length());
```

EDIT:
As noted below, I was wrong about the hasOwnProperty bit. It does work with XML, and it is a namespace issue that's causing your problem. You can make sure your XML is using the correct namespace by using this handy snippet:

```
if (myXML.namespace("") != undefined) {
    default xml namespace = myXML.namespace("");
}
```

Comment: hasOwnProperty works fine with XML nodes.  Check the docs on it:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/XML.html#hasOwnProperty()

Comment: Ah, you're correct! E4X is a bit of an odd duck since you can do various operations directly inline in ways that you really can't anywhere else in ActionScript.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but in case others have this same issue, here's another way of doing it. Rather than using .length(), you can check for the existence of a namespaced node using QName like so:

```
var xml:XML = 
<ns:outernode xmlns:ns="urn:ns:1.0">
    <ns:innernode>Here is some text content</ns:innernode>
</ns:outernode>;
var ns:Namespace = new Namespace("urn:ns:1.0");
var q:QName = new QName(ns, "innernode");
var b:Boolean = xml.hasOwnProperty(q);
trace("Has innernode: " + b);
```

This will return true. The QName q represents the fully qualified nodename "ns:innernode".

Comment: Really good solution, for my case, i had to use a bit different;                    
var ns:Namespace = new Namespace("name-space", "http : //www.company.com/name-space");
var q:QName = new QName(ns, "NameSpace");

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem resides in the namespace.  Try it without, or try `xmlns:letters = "letters"`

Comment: removing the namespace is not an option, unfortunately. .length() works great though.